# How to read RTDB randomly generated node and it's value?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, telegram-bot

Below is my typescript code and its already connected to telegram and managed to sent a message.
Currently I'm trying to tinker with it even more by reading the randomly generated node Arduino and MQ7 created and sending it as a message on telegram.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as express from "express";
import * as cors from "cors";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();
const bot = express();

bot.use(cors( {origin: true}));

bot.post("/", async function(req, res) {
  const telegramText = req.body;
  req.body.message &&
  req.body.message.chat &&
  req.body.message.chat.id &&
  req.body.message.from &&
  req.body.message.from.first_name;

  if (telegramText) {
    const chat_id = req.body.message.chat.id;
    const first_name = req.body.message.from.first_name;
    const receivedMessage = req.body.message.text;

    //  Define your RTDB Reference
    const rtdbReference = admin.database().ref("Sensor MQ7");
    const mq7ref = rtdbReference.child("-NHi7dBPMlVi6hXrnI03");
    const valref = mq7ref.child("MQ7");
    //  Fetch the data
    const snap = await valref.get();
    const snapValue = snap.val();
    //  Inject snapvalue in the response

    return res.status(200).send({
      method: "sendMessage",
      chat_id,
      text: `${first_name}\n${receivedMessage}\n${snapValue}`,
    });
  }
  return res.status(200).send({status: "An error occured"});
});

export const router = functions.https.onRequest(bot);
```

The typescript code works I figured out how to read entries from the database and write it into telegram as well as learning a little bit about the reference and functions. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to output the value whenever a new node is created. The new node are randomly generated @ Arduino and mq7 gas sensor. Basically whenever the sensor picks up dangerous amount of carbon monoxide, it'll send the input to firebase, and a new node is created with a new value. I've classified the **Parent = Sensor MQ7**, **Middle child = "randomly generated node"**, **Last child = MQ7**. Any help, advice, or recommendation is greatly appreciated. Please explain like I'm 5 because I just started doing all of it this week and I'm really really new to cloud functions. Thank you!

[RTDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7H1Z.png)

Answer (score 1):

> The typescript code (for sending to Telegram) works and right now I'm
> trying to figure out how to read entries from the database and write
> it into telegram

In a Cloud Function you need to use the [Node.js Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin) to interact with the Firebase services.

Here is how to read the data at a specific [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference) in the Realtime Database:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as express from "express";
import * as cors from "cors";

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';   <== NEW
admin.initializeApp();                     <== NEW

const bot = express();

bot.use(cors( {origin: true}));

bot.post("/", async function(req, res) {
  const telegramText = req.body;
  req.body.message &&
  req.body.message.chat &&
  req.body.message.chat.id &&
  req.body.message.from &&
  req.body.message.from.first_name;


  if (telegramText) {
    const chat_id = req.body.message.chat.id;
    const first_name = req.body.message.from.first_name;
    const receivedMessage = req.body.message.text;

    //Define your RTDB Reference
    const rtdbReference = admin.admin.database().ref('foo/bar');
    // Fetch the date
    const snap = await rtdbReference.get();
    const snapValue = snap.val();
    // Do whatever you need with snapValue to inject it in your response...

    return res.status(200).send({
      method: "sendMessage",
      chat_id,
      text: `Hello ${first_name}, \n You sent us message: ${receivedMessage}`,
    });
  }

  return res.status(200).send({status: "An error occured"});

  
});

export const router = functions.https.onRequest(bot);
```

Comment: Thank you! i managed to send the data into telegram however im not quite understand how to define RTDB reference. Sorry for asking again. I've added the screenshot of my RTDB and would love to receive some guidance

Comment: Hi. You have to tell me what you want to send back, which DB node. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once) will also help you.

Comment: Hi. As of today I managed to understand a little bit about the reference and got my code working thanks to you, but now I'm facing another problem because the node are randomly generated and I'm having trouble referencing whenever a new node is created. I've updated the post so it's much clearer. Thank you so much for the materials and guidance and would really love to receive some pointers from you again.